Constructing elements of Fin type after using `<?`
I'm ... tired of struggling with this question? I'm trying to construct elements of a Fin set, and not succeeding. Here's a simple definition that hopefully clarifies my difficulty:
t1 : ℕ → Fin 100
t1 n with n <? 100
... | true because x = # n
... | false because y = # 99

This is (intended to be a) function that accepts a natural number and returns an element of Fin 100. If the given number is (say) 4, this function should return # 4. If it's not less than 100, the result should just be # 99.
The issue I'm encountering is that Agda is reporting an unsatisfied constraint. Specifically, # n is highlighted, with the message
_m<n_8 : Relation.Nullary.True (n <? 100)  [ at /Users/bumblefinger/asm.agda:22,15-18 ]

I'm interpreting this as meaning that Agda cannot type-check my program because it ... needs a value of type Relation.Nullary.True (n <? 100)  ? Which sounds to me very much like x, which (checking it by inserting a hole) has type Relation.Nullary.Reflects (suc n ≤ 100) true. However, as far as I can tell there's no way to "supply" x as an argument, implicit or otherwise, to #.
I'm hoping that I'm missing something simple, here!
Many thanks in advance for any help...
Oh... not homework, FWIW :)

Data.Fin.#_ is primarily meant to be used with number literals, as in # 99, taking advantage of proof by reflection (making Agda generate a witness of the inequality by computation instead of supplying one yourself). If you already have a witness that the inequality holds, you can use fromℕ< instead:
t1 : ℕ → Fin 100
t1 n with n <? 100
... | yes n<100 = fromℕ< n<100
... | no _ = # 99

(Note the use of the handy yes/no pattern synonyms.)

Awesome! Many thanks. So, to clarify, this constraint is saying "I need it to be decidable whether n is less than 100", which would be the case if I supplied a concrete number.

Something like that. You need to know enough about n that the decision computes to "true", so that True (n <? 100) evaluates to ⊤ and Agda knows how to solve that.
